# Prove that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^{\alpha}}{(1+p)^n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $p>0$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ then $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n^{\alpha}}{(1+p)^n}=0.$$

No ideas how to prove it. Can anyone help please?

Prove without using logarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}$, and perform the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) for convergence of this series:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{(n+1)^\alpha}{(1+p)^{n+1}} \cdot\frac{(1+p)^n}{n^\alpha}\right| = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^\alpha \frac{1}{1+p} \right| = \frac{1}{1+p} < 1$$

As this limit is less than 1, the series is convergent, which is only possible if the sequence $\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Very Elegant proof! +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_n = \frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}$.

we have $u_{n+1}=u_n \times\frac{(n+1)^\alpha}{n^\alpha (1+p)}$.

It is sufficient that $\frac{(n+1)^\alpha}{n^\alpha (1+p)} < 1$ and this occurs
if $(n+1)^\alpha < n^\alpha (1+p)$ which implies $n+1 < n (1+p)^{1/\alpha}$.

This last inequality is true when n is sufficiently great ($n> n_0$) as $(1+p)^{1/\alpha}>1$.

So the sequence is decreasing to 0 for all $n > n_0$.
($n_0$ is function of $p$).

Answer (score -2):

Take the logarithm and show that it goes to -infinity. If the logarithm goes to -infinity, then the sequence itself goes to 0.

Comment: Can it be proven without using logarithm?

Comment: "Prove without using logarithm." !