# How to solve this limit problem? $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n} = 0$

Tags: limits

For $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b > 0$ show that 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n} = 0$

Comment: I see that you earned a badge for having visited the site's [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)?  Start acting like you've read it.

Comment: This question lacks context [as described in the FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). Please improve your question to add some context; for instance, what you have tried, or what is giving you difficulty.

Comment: Duplicate: $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n^{\alpha}}{(1+p)^n}=0$: $                                          \ $ [$[1]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1541377/201168), [$[2]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/238513/201168).

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)^k}{(1+b)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n}}=\frac{1}{1+b}<1$$
hence $\sum_{n} \frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n}<\infty$ converges, so $\frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n}\to 0$

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n}$$

Show it converges for $b>0$ by the ratio test, hence we must have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n}=0$$

For $b>0$, because if we didn't than by the divergence test the series would diverge for $b>0$ but it doesn't.

Comment: Isn't this the same as Taktheh_pareh's answer?

Comment: Yes, but it was a little different until he edited.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\geqslant2k$ we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
(1+b)^n&>\binom{n}{k+1}\\\\&=\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k)}{(k+1)!}\\\\&>\dfrac{n^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}
\end{aligned}
$$
and hence $n^k/(1+b)^n<2^{k+1}(k+1)!/n$ and since the RHS of the inequality tends to zero as $n\to\infty,$ we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Using $a^{n} = e^{n \, \ln(a)}$ then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{(1+b)^n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} n^k \, e^{- n \, \ln(1 + b)} \to 0
\end{align}
since $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-a \,n} \to 0$ faster than $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{k} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $n\ge\frac1{\left(1+b\right)^{\frac1{2k}}-1}$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
&=\frac{(n+1)^k(1+b)^n}{n^k(1+b)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^k}{1+b}\\[6pt]
&\le\frac1{\sqrt{1+b}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry for my earlier words; I just looked back to see that today I too answered a low-quality post by same user.  So far the OP's strategy seems to be working for him/her.

Comment: Everyone has their opinion of what constitutes a low quality question, and they are free to express that either by comment or by voting to close. Answers may point out that the question, or at least the answers thereto, have merit, but if the question is of low quality, comments or votes may prompt the author to improve the question. Withholding answers, in conjunction with comments or votes, might also prompt question improvement, but when there are already decent answers, I don't think withholding further answers will make much difference.